# Projeto Ionic nao executa no android

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou tentando executar um projeto ionic no android mas quando executo `ionic run android` retorna uma excessao.

Como resolver ?

**Ionic info**

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v4.2.2
```

**Excessao**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você enxerga seu aparelho no Android Studio?

Comment: @MarceloBonus sim, e no adb tbm. `adb devices -l` ele exibe normalmente. Eu executo um projeto nativo no Android Studio tbm, mas o Ionic nao vai.

Comment: tente remover a plataforma android e adicionar novamente.

Comment: Tenda usar o PdaNet - http://pdanet.co/.

Answer (score 0):

O tempo esgotou na busca pelo seu dispositivo, você pode aumentar este tempo manualmente (não recomendável), comigo funcionou.

**platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js**

Localize este trecho de código

```
if (!error || "string" === typeof error) {
  error = new Error(error || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms");
  error.code = "ETIMEDOUT";
}
  deferred.reject(error);
}, ms);
```

substitua o **ms**

```
if (!error || "string" === typeof error) {
  error = new Error(error || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms");
  error.code = "ETIMEDOUT";
}
  deferred.reject(error);
}, "1600");
```